# Where is EJB method run

Tags: java, netweaver

I'm calling an EJB method remotely using next code:

```
RemCallRemote rc = null;
String Text = "";   
Properties props = new Properties();    

//Filling the properties for connection to a remote server
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sap.engine.services.jndi.InitialContextFactoryImpl");

props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "hostaddress:50004");

props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "LOGINNAME");

props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "*****");  

props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "com.sap.engine.services");    

InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);

//getting a reference to an interface
rc = (RemCallRemote)ctx.lookup("ejb:/appName=sap.com/RemoteCallEAR, jarName=RemoteCallEJB.jar, beanName=RemCall, interfaceName=RemCallRemote");

//calling an EJB method
Text = rc.Check();
```

The code works fine, but my question is: Where is the EJB method run? Is it run always on 'hostaddress' machine or anywhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host address is where the JNDI server is. It's not always the same server where the EJB's themselves are running, though in most cases it is.

For exceptional cases, you can register an EJB from server1 in a JNDI server on server2 that serves as some sort of cluster manager. Not really sure if it's possible with SAP, but on e.g. WebSphere you can.

Comment: Your answer is very informative. Thank you. You are right. The SAP server is a cluster of several Java application servers. Even if I call the EJB using a certain physical server name (It's possible to do this), it will be no warranty that the EJB will be run on the certain physical server. This is decided by a SAP Java managing services.

Answer (score 0):

EJB architecture is based on RMI and uses RMI's [Stubs and Skeletons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-arch2.html).

In your example RemCallRemote is the stub and all it does is send `Check()` method call back to server.

These days EJB does not use Skeletons any more and relies on container to handle Stubs requests.

Answer (score 0):

AppServers use JNDi to share information of EJBs. When you deploy EJB, a [CORBA](http://www.ois.com/Products/what-is-corba.html) compliant stub is registered with JNDI service of the AppServer. By 'CORBA compliant stub' I mean this is something beyond RMI, and is platform independent architecture. So theoretically, the client of EJB could be a COBOL or C program too!
Clients always look up the JNDi service and ask for stub of the EJB. This stub naturally has to be serializable. Suffices to say that it contains enough information so that the client can create an object which acts as a proxy to the real EJB. So at this point, situation is, EJB object is on server, and a proxy is on client. By proxy I mean, it hides network level communication details.
Client code now calls methods on proxy, and these are transparently called over CORBA protocol to the EJB object on server.
So to answer your q, EJB object is always on server. It's proxy is constructed on client using the CORBA stub registered on JNDI service. The EJB server, JNDI service, and client can be on different machines. Usually the JNDI service is a part of the AppServer where EJB is deployed. The client is usually a web application usually deployed on same AppServer as where EJB is deployed, though not necessarily. Client is also sometimes a thick client like Swing based, or C#.NET based GUI app on client desktop/laptop.